# Display the same Backbone.js Validation Errors Message in multiple locations on same page

Tags: backbone.js

So I've been using the n-time backbone.js validation (https://github.com/n-time/backbone.validations) for client side form validation with great success in my current project. The thing is that while it works great with errors messages below the field, I would like there to be, I need the error message to show up in two locations. So I did something like this

```
All Errors are listed here: 
<span class="error" name="adultFName1Error" /> <br /><br />


.... further down the page....


<label class="form_label" for="adultFName1">First Name:</label>
<input id="adultFName1" type="text" name="adultFName1" size="30" class="validate validate-NotBlank validate-FirstName"/>
<span class="error" name="adultFName1Error" />
```

This works great, but the issue is when I add another field to validate, so when its looks like this:

```
All Errors are listed here: 
<span class="error" name="adultFName1Error" /> <br /><br />
<span class="error" name="adultLName1Error" /> <br /><br />

.... further down the page....

<label class="form_label" for="adultFName1">First Name:</label>
<input id="adultFName1" type="text" name="adultFName1" size="30" class="validate validate-NotBlank validate-FirstName"/>
<span class="error" name="adultFName1Error" />

<label class="form_label" for="adultLName1">Last Name:</label>
<input id="adultLName1" type="text" name="adultLName1" size="30" class="validate validate-NotBlank validate-LastName" />
<span class="error" name="adultLName1Error" />
```

Only the first error (adult1Fname1Error) displays correctly at the top of the page. All  errors display correctly to their associated field input, but only

```
 <span class="error" name="adultFName1Error" /> <br /><br />
```

displays correctly at the top of the page. (The rest just don't show up at the top of the page).

Is there a technique I'm missing to have the backbone validate error message to show up twice on the same page for multiple input fields?

Comment: could you share some of the model code that triggers validation and binds to errors?

Comment: are you targeting the spans by the class (e.g. .error or span.error)?

Answer (score 0):

Similar case I have faced when I wanted to show the error messages to the left side of the input text-box. For that I have just added style="float:left; to my html code and it worked